# Store Backward slash and forward slash in java string

Tags: java, string, odata, special-characters

I am parsing below string value into OData query through java code.

```
objects.put("EndDate", "\/Date(1441756800)\/";
```

How can i parse the **/Date(1441756800)/** into a string in java.

I have tried with below :

```
objects.put("EndDate", ""\\""//"Date(1441756800)""\\""//"";
```

throws error:(

Comment: You don't have to escape `/` (forward slashes). Just use `"/Date(1441756800)/"`

Comment: Odata is not accepting the "/Date(1441756800)/" format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never used OData so I may not understand your question correctly, but if you are asking how to write `\/Date(1441756800)\/` as String then you need to escape `\` as it is String special character (used for instance when escaping or when creating other special characters like line separators `\n`).

So try with `"\\/Date(1441756800)\\/"`

Answer (score 1):

Try this - `objects.put("EndDate", "'Date(1441756800)'";`

Comment: Cant change the format.i want to parse \/Date(1441756800)\/ exactly